PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 19): A Christmas puzzle in (1)225 characters
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
(This puzzle is also inspired by these puzzles.)
There is nothing that will help you solve the puzzle in the following paragraph, and it is not actually true. It is just for flavor.
Well, it's just 6 days until Christmas this year, but I must admit that I'm not looking forward to it as much as all of you are. Why is that? Well, last year at about this time people were supposed to be buying Christmas presents, but somehow everyone managed to forget me! I was rather put out by this revelation, as you might imagine, so I created this puzzle to tell everyone how I really felt. Your goal is simple: to answer the question, How did I feel after I didn't get any Christmas presents last year?
Good luck!

Text version:

Island greeting to Santa’s scroll: $?+#:⌉ᤅጅᐘԄᐕᤅ᠅औЅԘ↓→⊞⚐naughty gift:32224::?:135XX1νX∀4☴ KEYS: 3455165421 12333651 543432312765 661765653

Hint 1:

 Unlike the puzzles this is inspired by, there are really only five unique puzzles here. The first four will give you a word each, and each will almost fit one of the keys in some way.

Hint 2:

 music, moreso than you'd think. Every puzzle here (except arguably one) involves Christmas music in some way.

Hint 3:
I'd like to see this one solved, so for the sake of quickness I've included a hint today for each individual mini-puzzle this time:
Hint 3.1:

 In an earlier draft of the puzzle,  was ,  was ♂, and "to" was replaced by an emoji of a household item commonly found in a garage or attic.

Hint 3.2:

 The characters "+#" have a double meaning for this sub-puzzle (and they're not the only thing with a double meaning in the [greater] puzzle.) One of the meanings involves addition of numbers, but for the other, what besides addition could follow a plus sign with numbers?

Hint 3.3 (this sub-puzzle has already been solved, but I'll include this anyway for future solvers):

 ⊞⚐ is a part of this puzzle, not the next. In addition, the  emojis are mainly thematic; they could be replaced by slashes or dashes or any other separator.

Hint 3.4

 This is an analogy (the naughty gift relates to 32224 as what relates to 135XX1νX∀4☴?) It also might help to look at the official names of some of the more confusing symbols here.


"There is nothing that will help you solve the puzzle in this intro paragraph, nor is it actually true. It is just for flavor."  So either it's not just for flavor, or there is indeed something in it that will help us (or both).

It's the intro paragraph that isn't true.  Just making sure nobody would feel it is an actual rant about someone.

A partial community wiki to catalogue progress on this puzzle so far in the PSE Advent Calendar 2024 chatroom...
From the OP's hint, it looks like this string of emojis can be separated into four mini-puzzles to produce a word each, and one final meta-puzzle to make use of them. One mini-puzzle has been solved in the chatroom by @Bladeski and @Stiv:

This section conceals a...

 nonogram puzzle. Many of these emojis can be linked to the seasonal song The Twelve Days of Christmas, and particular days:

 Day 1: A partridge in a pear tree (the tree emoji)
 Day 2: Two turtle doves (the turtle emoji)
 Day 3: Three French hens (the chicken emoji)
 Day 4: Four calling birds (the telephone emoji)
 Day 5: Five gold rings (the ring emoji)
 Day 6: Six geese a-laying (the goose emoji)

 If we substitute each of these emojis with the number of the day on which they were first gifted, and treat the gift emojis as just dividers, then the downwards and rightwards arrows suggest that what follows after them can be interpreted as the down and across clues for a nonogram puzzle. The resulting nonogram is uniquely solvable:



 The final two emojis in this section - ⊞⚐ - instruct us to divide the resulting grid into 4 equal squares and interpret each as if the white cells indicate the positions of a signaller's arms in flag semaphore. Doing so gives us the four letter answer COMB.




(Posting this as a partial community wiki since the puzzle was posted over 40 hours ago and the OP might like to see partial progress made in chat...) Please do feel free to join or start discussions in the Advent Calendar chatroom if you have ideas for other parts of this puzzle or would like to get involved in solving it!

As I've just said in the chatroom, this is all correct so far, nice start.

It is still not solved :(
